# Firebase notification onMessageReceived show the same notification as when app in background

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I am sending messages to my app from the Console and I managed to have the app react as I want, when it is in background. So basically there is a notification shown by the SDK and when the user taps it and the app starts, I have some custom data fields to use to build a dialog message.

Since I also want the app to react when on foreground I've added the service and I've noticed that the `RemoteMessage` also contains a `getNotification()` method which returns `RemoteMessage.Notification` which I suppose is used by the SDK to show the notification when app in background.

Is there an easy way to simply use that retrieved notification and display it, just as when the app is in background?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37845174/5296734) may works for you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There sure is. Just override `FirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived` and get the notification body as in this example from the Firebase Cloud Messaging documentation:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}
```

See the Firebase Cloud Messaging documentation for [receiving downstream messages on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream#sample-receive) under "Override onMessageReceived".

Comment: Also once you receive the message it is up to you to generate the notification. See the sendNotification method in the FCM Android sample here: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java#L57

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping for a more simple approach, like inside onMessageReceived to simply take the notification and display it, as how the SDK does it when app in background with all the custom fields and icon and message. Since there is no such simple way, I'm using the approched from the answer and do my own notification which in the end will be similar with the one generated by the SDK.

Comment: can anybody solve this issue ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750548/show-notification-of-firebase-message-onrecieved-when-app-is-in-background-throu