# Firebase Notification receive separately when app background and also can't store notification on shared preference when app is in background

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My android FCM notification is perfectly working when the app is running. I am also getting data notifications through Freebase console.

But when my app is in the background, notifications are separately displayed and if the user clears the notification without a tap on the notification, we can't do anything.

Is it possible to store the notification in shared preferences when the app is in background ?

This is possible with GCM, but I have no idea about FCM.

and other thing i  am sending notification with data through freebase console. perfectly data come also  when user tap on notification but without tap on notification user clear notification i cant do anything.

i want to store notification when user not tap on notification and clear notification

please help me

Comment: Is the notification module marked as a service?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show Notification of Firebase Message onRecieved when App is in Background Through api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750548/show-notification-of-firebase-message-onrecieved-when-app-is-in-background-throu)